# How can I expand the size of my Ubuntu installation without reinstalling?

Tags: partitioning, wubi, disk-usage

About a week ago I used the windows installer to install Ubuntu to an extra hard drive I had because I've heard so much about it. Since [I guess] Wubi is meant for people with limited disk space who want to dual boot, it only allocates 30G of space to Ubuntu.

My situtation is that I have an extra ~170G of disk space that isn't being used, since I'm not dual-booting from one disk. Is there a way to make Ubuntu use that free space without reinstalling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wubi is great for experimentation of Ubuntu. If you really want more than 30 GBs of space you might want to consider actually dual-booting. The thing is that Wubi uses Windows' native filesystem and is very susceptible to the corruptions and downsides of it. To be using Ubuntu heavily enough to warrant over 30 GBs of usage... it might be worth your while to take the plunge and just install it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot resize while Ubuntu runs, I would suggest Deleting the leftover space and making it mount as /home.

OR

Boot up the Live CD and Boot the Partition Editor. Grow the partition using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

installing would allow you to use the disc space And hear are some ubuntu uses ext4 file system. ubuntu can run at full speed. easer to manage when on two different partitions,